# R tidyquant - problem with col_rename in tq_transform

Tags: programming

Getting an error when trying to rename columns of a transformed tibble via tq_transform. Checked the documentation and I think I am following the syntax correctly. Below is a reproducible example along with the error messages.

```
library(tidyquant)

tickers <- c("SPY", "XLY", "XLP")

prices <- tickers %>%
          tq_get("stock.prices") %>%
          group_by(symbol.x)

returns <- tq_transform(prices, 
                        ohlc_fun = Ad, 
                        transform_fun = periodReturn,
                        period = "monthly", 
                        type = "arithmetic", 
                        col_rename = c("ticker", "date", "returns"))
```

Warning messages:
1: In coerce_to_tibble(ret, date_col_name, time_zone, col_rename) :
  Could not rename columns
2: In coerce_to_tibble(ret, date_col_name, time_zone, col_rename) :
  Could not rename columns
3: In coerce_to_tibble(ret, date_col_name, time_zone, col_rename) :
  Could not rename columns

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, misinterpreted the exact function of col_rename. Originally thought this would work as dplyr::rename and rename **all** columns in the resulting tbl, but now understand that it seems to only work for the transformed column.

The below amendment to the code works fine.

```
returns <- tq_transform(prices, ohlc_fun = Ad, transform_fun = periodReturn,
                    period = "monthly", type = "arithmetic", 
                    col_rename = "returns")
```